# Django app for extracting 2 level urls from given link

Tags: python, django, csv

I am new to Django and need guidance. i want to create an django app which extracts url from given link in textview and give output as a csv file. i have created django app, made a html form to get input and its running too. but i cant proceed because i don't know how to pass the textview input to beautifulsoup python function and create a csv file with all the links present in that html file directed by given url in textview.

**Home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<center><h1 style="color:grey;">URL EXTRACTER</h1></center>

<form method="post">
                <div style="clear: both;"></div>
            <div class="input">
                <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="true"/>
                <textarea  style=" position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    height: 30px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -250px; /* margin is -0.5 * dimension */
    margin-top: -25px; " cols="50" rows="2"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
           <button style=" position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    top: 60%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px; /* margin is -0.5 * dimension */
    margin-top: -25px;  ">Scan</button>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def home(request):
    context={}
    template="home.html"
    return render(request,template,context)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$','lwc.views.home',name='home'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

Comment: You need a view to handle your form data, and submit your form to that view. You probably also want to include the CSRF token in that form, and take advantage of the template system in Django rather than just writing plain HTML. All these things are demonstrated in the great tutorial at the Django project site: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: I second the addition of a csrf token in your post request. This [django doc page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/) explains why you want to use it.

Comment: if you can help me with code. it will be really a great help. thank you